# ionic 2 : variable is modified but doesn't change in the view HTML

Tags: javascript, angular, variables, ionic2, refresh

I'm new to ionic 2 and I have a problem you guys might think it's easy to handle, but i'm blocked on it.

I have a variable that I want to show in my page (on the smartphone screen), I put that variable between {{ myVar }} and it is display by the HTML on the screen. Till here, no problem. When the value of myVar change because i press a button, the value is updated to the screen too. But when a function does modify the value of myVar, the value of myVar is update in the code (i saw it on console.log) but not in the view of the screen.

Can you guys help me out please, I didn't find any information about this problem. Maybe there is a tutorial somewhere that explain how it works?

Thank you

EDIT : Sorry, I wasn't sure if my source code would help, but here we go :

My code go like this, I scan devices around with BLE. And it display the result of all the devices with BLE available, I connect to the one I need and display all the services that the device provides. (I use cordova plugin BLE)

This is the HTML view of all the service that the device i am connected to provides.

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-navbar>
  <ion-title>{{device.name}}</ion-title>
 </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
 <ion-buttons>
  <button ion-button (click) = "disconnect(device.id)" block>Disconnect</button>
 </ion-buttons>
 <ion-card *ngFor="let characteristic of characteristics">
 <ion-card-header>UUID: {{characteristic.characteristic}}</ion-card-header>
<ion-card-content>
  <p>Properties: {{characteristic.properties}}<br>
    Service: {{characteristic.service}} <br>
  <ion-buttons end>
    <button *ngIf="displayNotifyButton(characteristic.properties)== true" ion-button (click)="startNotify(device.id, characteristic.service, characteristic.characteristic)" round>Notify</button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
<p>AMOUNT OF MONEY : {{money}}</p>
```

What it's important here, is the button Notify that runs the function startNotify(...). and the paragraph

AMOUNT OF MONEY : {{money}}

{{money}} is the variable that get modified but does not change in HTML view.

Here is the function startNotify :

```
startNotify(deviceID, serviceUUID, characteristicUUID) {
   this.isNotify = true;
   this.ble.startNotification(deviceID, serviceUUID, characteristicUUID).subscribe(buffer => {
   var dataView = new DataView(buffer);
   var coin = dataView.getUint8(0);
   console.log("## NOTIFY VALUE ## " + coin);
   this.sortCoin(coin);
   console.log('## MONEY ## '+ this.money);
   }, error => {
   console.log("## NOTIFY ERROR ## " + error);
   });
 }
```

Here it's the constructor :

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private ble: BLE) {
    this.device = this.navParams.get('device');
    console.log("## DEVICE INFORMATION ##" + JSON.stringify(this.device));
    this.connecting = true;
    this.isNotify = false;
    this.connect(this.device.id);
    this.money = 0;
    }
```

And here it's the sortCoin method, that is only a switch and modify the value of variable money

```
sortCoin(value){
 switch (value){
  case 1:
    this.money += 0.1;
    break;
  case 2:
    this.money += 0.2;
    break;
  case 4:
    this.money += 0.5;
    break;
  case 8:
    this.money += 1;
    break;
  case 16:
    this.money += 2;
    break;
  case 32:
    this.money += 5;
    break;
  case 65:
    this.money -= 0.1;
    break;
  case 66:
    this.money -= 0.2;
    break;
  case 68:
    this.money -= 0.5;
    break;
  case 72:
    this.money -= 1;
    break;
  case 80:
    this.money -= 2;
    break;
  case 96:
    this.money -= 5;
    break;
 }
}
```

So my problem is : When a notification is done by the device, it send an array buffer which I interpret and send it to the method sortCoin. In the method sortCoin, the value of the variable money is modified (I can see it with the console log) but the amount doesn't change in the HTML view, which still show 0, because money is set to 0 in the constructor.

I hope my source code will help you to figure my problem out :)

Thank you

Comment: to help you, we need code update that to post

Comment: Welcome to SO.. please provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it should help you.

Comment: No one have a solution? :'(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved my problem with NgZone

```
this.zone.run(() => {
      this.getValueOf2 = data.amount;
    });
```